# how to send email with gmail compose from my application?

Tags: django, gmail

When the current user of my web-application select other users who will send them email with Gmail, i want to redirect him to the gmail compose ([Link](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=mm#inbox?compose=new)) and then type his message.

In my django view, before clicking on "Mail To" i have retrieved a list of distination users.
Is it possible to affect those users to destination in gmail ?

Comment: Do you want to include multiple recipients emails?

Comment: yes, and the recipients are sended from my app to gmail and affected to the "TO input"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include multiple recipients then in template do it like this:

```
<a href="mailto:{% for user in users %}{% if not forloop.last %}{{ user.email }},{% else %}{{ user.email }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">Send email</a>
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3QAYu/2/) in jsfiddle. You can add subject and body also:

```
<a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com,cde@gmail.com?subject=test subject&body=hi there" target="_blank">Send email with subject and body</a>
```

See more tips and tricks [here](http://www.angelfire.com/dc/html-webmaster/mailto.htm)

Comment: this, it opens to me outlouk window and users email are affected to destination, but how to affect them to gmail destination here : https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=mm#inbox?compose=new ?

Comment: It depends on the browser default email client. Yours is outlook. To make gmail your default email client for sending emails follow this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10966?hl=en)